# struts form inside table

Tags: struts2, tiles

Basically I have 4 tiles,Header,Content,Left and Right.

When i try to display a table inside a form ,for arranging form elements,My whole structure of the master page is being changed.

Initially the structure which i have defined in the master page ie base layout is being changed and table is being deformed when i create a table inside a form in some middle page. Why is this happening?

I have arranged the  and other tiles using a table.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

which theme you are using in struts2?default theme tend to create some markup while rendering the view so that might causes an issue.you can go ahead with simple theme.
by default it is xhtml and you an switch themes per page basis or for entire application

here are the details

[Struts2 Themes](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/can-i-change-theme-on-a-per-page-basis.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the simple theme on your form:

```
<s:form action="youraction" method="post" name="yourform" theme="simple">
...
</s:form>
```

ok.